# Invalid files produced after encrypting/decrypting

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, byte, aes

I have made a cryptography application and it was working fine until I started doing the encryption/decryption in blocks. here's my encryption/decryption code:

```
public static class AESCryptography
{
    private const int keysize = 256;
    public static void Encrypt(string Input, string passPhrase)
    {
        var chunkSize = 16;
        PasswordDeriveBytes password = new PasswordDeriveBytes(passPhrase, null);
        byte[] keyBytes = password.GetBytes(keysize / 8);
        FileStream fsOutput = File.OpenWrite(Input.Substring(0, Input.LastIndexOf('.')) + ".aent");
        FileStream fsInput = File.OpenRead(Input);
        RijndaelManaged symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged();
        symmetricKey.GenerateIV();
        symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        ICryptoTransform encryptor = symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, symmetricKey.IV);
        CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(fsOutput, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        fsOutput.Write(symmetricKey.IV, 0, symmetricKey.IV.Length);
        for (long i = 0; i < fsInput.Length; i += chunkSize)
        {
            byte[] chunkData = new byte[chunkSize];
            int bytesRead = 0;
            while ((bytesRead = fsInput.Read(chunkData, 0, chunkSize)) > 0)
            {
                if (bytesRead != chunkSize)
                {
                    for (int x = bytesRead - 1; x < chunkSize; x++)
                    {
                        chunkData[x] = 0;
                    }
                }
                cryptoStream.Write(chunkData, 0, chunkSize);
            }
        }
        cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
        cryptoStream.Dispose();
        fsOutput.Dispose();
        fsInput.Dispose();
        encryptor.Dispose();
        symmetricKey.Dispose();
        password.Dispose();
    }

    public static void Decrypt(string Input, string passPhrase)
    {
        var chunkSize = 16;
        PasswordDeriveBytes password = new PasswordDeriveBytes(passPhrase, null);
        byte[] keyBytes = password.GetBytes(keysize / 8);
        FileStream fsInput = File.OpenRead(Input);
        FileStream fsOutput = File.OpenWrite(Input.Substring(0, Input.LastIndexOf('.')) + ".txt");
        byte[] initVectorBytes = new byte[16];
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8];
        fsInput.Read(buffer, 0, 8);
        long fileLength = BitConverter.ToInt64(buffer, 0);
        fsInput.Read(initVectorBytes, 0, 16);
        RijndaelManaged symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged();
        symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        ICryptoTransform decryptor = symmetricKey.CreateDecryptor(keyBytes, initVectorBytes);
        CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(fsOutput, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        for (long i = 0; i < fsInput.Length; i += chunkSize)
        {
            byte[] chunkData = new byte[chunkSize];
            int bytesRead = 0;
            while ((bytesRead = fsInput.Read(chunkData, 0, chunkSize)) > 0)
            {
                cryptoStream.Write(chunkData, 0, bytesRead);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

if I encrypt a .txt file that says for example: "hello world! the app works!!" i will get some awkward Chinese text mixed with symbols I've never seen.

Comment: Just an advice, you should really consider using `using` statements.

Comment: I did but I was getting errors so I thought I should stick to basics until this is solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've left some code incomplete. This code here in Decrypt is a problem:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[8];
fsInput.Read(buffer, 0, 8);
long fileLength = BitConverter.ToInt64(buffer, 0);
```

This reads eight bytes that were never written by Encrypt, shifting everything you read after that by eight bytes. Comment out those three lines and your code works.

You are also missing a cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock() after your loop in Decrypt. Because of the 8-byte offset by the bug, you would get a CryptographicException "Length of the data to decrypt is invalid." (You missed 8 bytes.) But after commenting out those lines, FlushFinalBlock() will succeed.